# How to enable/disable device wise closed caption settings on iOS?

Tags: ios, avplayer, closed-captions

When the accessibility option is turned on the device, we're not able to turn off the closed caption by setting the `closedCaptionEnabled` option for the `AVPlayer` instance as we normally would. Is there a way to bypass such option or even to test if it's enabled to lock the CC button if necessary?

Comment: May I know which version of iOS you are using? Are you purely using AVPlayer or you may have another player, such Brightcove, which has AVPlayer embedded inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through each AVPlayerItemTrack and enable/disable it as you wish.

This is how I do in one of my project. I show table of available CC tracks and when the user selects one I iterate through each track, enable the on that user selected and disable rest.

```
    //_selectedTrackIndex = userSelectedIndex;
    -(void) setSelectedTrackEnabled {
        for (AVPlayerItemTrack * t in [_playerItem tracks]) {
            if (counter == _selectedTrackIndex) {
                [t setEnabled:YES];
            } else {
                [t setEnabled:NO];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great for switching between tracks. However if I disable all the tracks to turn off CC, the most recent caption gets stuck on the screen and doesn't disappear. Does anyone know how to handle this?