# AVPlayer Closed Captions turn on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm creating custom video player, and i want to create toggle button for CC.

I saw this post : [IOS AVPlayer cannot disable closed captions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777781/ios-avplayer-cannot-disable-closed-captions)

So I tried :

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup *group = [self.avPlayer.currentItem.asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];

[self.avPlayer.currentItem  selectMediaOption:nil inMediaSelectionGroup:group];
```

Didn't work.. cc still visible.

also tried :

```
AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput *output = [[AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput alloc] init];
[output setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[output setSuppressesPlayerRendering:true];
[self.avPlayer.currentItem addOutput:output];
```

It's hide the the cc, but how can I unhide them? ,I tried:

```
[output setSuppressesPlayerRendering:true];
```

but the cc freeze on the screen.

thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: This is answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303052/how-to-enable-disable-device-wise-closed-caption-settings-on-ios

Answer (score 3):

Objective C: This one works for me. Even I wanted to do the same thing.

To off subtitles

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup *subtitleSelectionGroup = [_playerItem.asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
              
[_playerItem selectMediaOption:NULL inMediaSelectionGroup:subtitleSelectionGroup];
```

To show it again I do this:

```
AVMediaSelectionOption* option = [subtitleSelectionGroup.options objectAtIndex:subtitleIndex-1]; // I did -1 because OFF was 0 for my case 
         
[_playerItem selectMediaOption:option inMediaSelectionGroup:subtitleSelectionGroup];
```